# Duplicate Memory Allocation Java

Tags: java, android, memory, allocation

in my Code I have a method or multiple methods which declare some Objects like:

```
public void method{
ArrayList <Integer> al = new ArrayList<>(); 
//do smth else
}
```

I am calling These methods multiple times. Will be in every iteration new meomory allocated becuase of calling the new Operator?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a basic CS topic on how memory management works for programming languages (esp. in Java). Just in case you can't find the answer anywhere else: If you call this method several times, yes you create multiple copies of `al` in memory. But once the method ends, in Java, the object's reference is no longer used and the GC can free up the memory whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will have a new memory allocation every iteration, you can do like this to avoid multiple memory alloc

```
ArrayList <Integer> al = null; //make the declaration outside the method   
public void method{
    if (al == null){
        al= new ArrayList<>();
    }else{
        al.clear();}

//do smthing with you're arrayList here
  }
```

Comment: As a sidenote, doing something like this will make the code unclearer, while offering no real performance benefits.